# (400) Bad Request when trying to post simple value to an API

Tags: powershell, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have this `LoansController` for a web api

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LoansController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // POST api/loans
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {

    }
}
```

In PowerShell I can call

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:1113/api/loans -Body $postParams -Method Get
```

and it works fine (I get `value1` and `value2`)

But when I try

```
$postParams = "{'value':'123'}"
Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:1113/api/loans -Body $postParams -Method Post # -ContentType 'Application/json'
```

I just keep getting

> Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried adding `-ContentType 'Application/json'` but it made no difference

What am I missing?

I also tried `Invoke-RestMethod` but with the same results..

Next I removed `[FromBody]` from the `value` param but `value` now comes in as `null`

Comment: Send actual JSON string `$postParams = "\"123\""` or create a model that matches the json and use that in the action. Finally make sure the content type is set to the correct type

Comment: Get requests do not have a body

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Reason**

It just happens **because your action method is expecting a plain `string` from HTTP request's Body**:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] string value)
{

}
```

Here a **plain string** is a sequence of characters which is **quoted by `""`**. In other words, to represent the string, you need **include the quotes** before and after these characters when sending request to this action method.

If you do want to send the json string `{'value':'123'}` to server, you should use the following payload :

```
POST http://localhost:1113/api/loans HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

"{'value':'123'}"
```

Note : We **have to use doublequoted string**  ! Don't send string without the `""`

**How to fix**

1. To send a plain string, simply use the following `PowerShell` scripts :

   ```
   $postParams = "{'value':'123'}"
   $postParams = '"'+$postParams +'"'
   Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:1113/api/loans -Body $postParams  -Method Post  -ContentType 'application/json'
   ```
2. Or if you would like to send the payload with json, you could create a `DTO` to hold the `value` property:

   ```
   public class Dto{
       public string Value {get;set;}
   }
   ```

   and change your action method to be :

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public void Post(Dto dto)
   {
       var value=dto.Value;
   }
   ```

   Finally, you can invoke the following `PowerShell` scripts to send request :

   ```
   $postParams = '{"value":"123"}'
   Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:1113/api/loans -Body $postParams  -Method Post  -ContentType 'application/json'
   ```

These two approaches both work flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add headers

```
$url = 'http://localhost:1113/api/loans'
$head = @{'ContentType'='Application/json'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Body $postParams -Method Post -Headers $head
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try using `ConvertTo-Json` in the powershell command:

```
$postParams = @{ "value": "123"} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:1113/api/loans -Body $postParams -Method Post -ContentType "application/json"
```

If it still doesn't work I suggest creating a model (data transfer object) and using model binding to bind your string value. Edit the controller Post method as below:

```
public class MyModelDto {
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// POST api/loans
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] MyModelDto model)
{
    string value = model.Value;
}
```