# Sending JSON data in API via Ajax error and JSON data traversing problem

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

```
var data = {
        "ApplicationName": "Zadmin",
        "KanMainGroupList":
            [{
                "MainGroupName": "Settings",
                "KanSubGroupList": [{
                    "SubGroupName": "Signatures",
                    "SubGroupURL": "Common/HHALevelSettings.aspx",
                    "SubGroupQueryString": "HHA_ID=$HHA_ID$&HHAName=$HHA_Name$",
                    "KanFeatureSetList":
                        [{
                            "FeatureName": "Client Sign pop-up",
                            "Keywords": "Client,sign"
                        }],
                    "KanNanoGroupList": [{
                        "NanoGroupName": "Nano1",
                        "NanoGroupURL": "URL1",
                        "NanoGroupQueryString": "",
                        "KanFeatureSetList": [
                            {
                                "FeatureName": "",
                                "KeyWords": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }]
                }
                ]
            }

            ]
    };
```

I have a mongo document which has JSON data as above. Now when I try to send this data via jquery ajax , it throws error "input was not in valid format" or some syntax error. The ajax cal is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'api/HelpAPI',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),               
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        }).done(function () {

        })
```

The controller is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {

          //i tried to use FromForm in place or FromBody
          //i tried to use object datatype for value and  dynamic as well but in object the data 
               //doesn't come and in dynamic it is very difficult to work upon.
    }
```

Finally **using below method** i can get the data properly in **value** .

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] KanFeatureHelp value)
    { 
        List<KanMainGroup> mainGrp = new List<KanMainGroup>();
        List<KanSubGroup> subgrp = new List<KanSubGroup>();
        List<KanNanoGroup> nanogrp = new List<KanNanoGroup>();
        List<KanFeatureSet> SubGrpfeatureset = new List<KanFeatureSet>();
        List<KanFeatureSet> NanoGrpfeatureset = new List<KanFeatureSet>();

        //mainGrp = value.KanMainGroupList;
        //subgrp = value.KanMainGroupList;

        mainGrp = value.KanMainGroupList;
        foreach(var i in mainGrp)
        {
            subgrp = i.KanSubGroupList;
            foreach (var j in subgrp)
            {
                nanogrp = j.KanNanoGroupList;
                SubGrpfeatureset = j.KanFeatureSetList;
                foreach (var k in nanogrp)
                {
                    NanoGrpfeatureset = k.KanFeatureSetList;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Structure of KanFeatureHelp is as below :

```
namespace WebApplication5.Models
{
    public class KanFeatureHelp
    {
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public List<KanMainGroup> KanMainGroupList { get; set; }

    }

    public class KanMainGroup
    {
        public string MainGroupName { get; set; }
        public List<KanSubGroup> KanSubGroupList { get; set; }
    }

    public class KanSubGroup
    {
        public string SubGroupName { get; set; }
        public string SubGroupURL { get; set; }
        public string SubGroupQueryString { get; set; }
        public List<KanFeatureSet> KanFeatureSetList { get; set; }
        public List<KanNanoGroup> KanNanoGroupList { get; set; }
    }

    public class KanNanoGroup
    {
        public string NanoGroupName { get; set; }
        public string NanoGroupURL { get; set; }
        public string NanoGroupQueryString { get; set; }
        public List<KanFeatureSet> KanFeatureSetList { get; set; }
    }

    public class KanFeatureSet
    {
        public string FeatureName { get; set; }
        public string Keywords { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. What is wrong with my API call ? How does one actually gets to know what to set the content type/ data manipulation to send the data properly ? what if someone wants to send dynamic data/object ? how can one send some string data then ?
2. Is it possible if I could send the data as string and then deserialize back in c# code ?
3. the current objective is to add or remove any **MainGroup / SubGroup / NanoGroup/ FeatureName** in the current Jsondata which I believe will need traversing through the data. If I could get some lead on how to do that it would be of great help.
4. With the current working scenario the only level to which I can access data is *value.KanMainGroupList*. Thereafter it doesnt shows any subgroup list or other data. Is the implementation wrong ? Should I change something ?

Really appreciate your time and effort . Thank you so much.

Comment: in your ajax call please set the `dataType: "json",` and try again. Also try placing the post call inside try/catch bock to see if there were any unhandled exceptions.  Please share if you find any.

Comment: @Searching The `dataType` argument in jQuery Ajax calls is the expected *response* data type and setting it is only necessary at all if the server sends an incorrect `Content-Type` header. It does not refer to the data type you send - that's what `contentType` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is wrong with my API call

As you've already found, that's because the server expects a payload of `application/json`. You need include such a header in your request.

> How does one actually gets to know what to set the content type/ data manipulation to send the data properly

As you know, the most often used types are:

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: The initial default type when you submit a form. This is also the default type of most ajax clients(e.g. XMLHttpRequest/axios/fetch/...)
- `multipart/formdata`: This type is used when you want to submit a form that contains file. Also, if you're using the [`FormData` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData), you should use the content-type.
- `application/json`: As JSON becomes the de-facto standard payload of REST, `application/json` is quite popular.

ASP.NET Core can bind data from several places. A plain ASP.NET Core Controller (instead of `[ApiController]`) will receive parameters from route/query string/form data, unless you specify a `[FromBody]`. However, unlike the plain `Controller`, an `[ApiController]` will bind data from body (`[FromBody]`) implicitly. Anyway,

- if you expects a json payload, add a `[FromBody]` on the server. Also don't forget to add a `Content-Type: application/json` in your request.
- if you expects a form, either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/formdata`, you could add a `[FromForm]` on the server and then add the related Content-Type in your request.

> what if someone wants to send dynamic data/object

Although I don't think it's a good idea to receive dynamic data, if you like, you could use [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#the-dynamic-type).

> how can one send some string data then ?
>
> Is it possible if I could send the data as string and then deserialize back in c# code

Yes. The easiest way is using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to send a payload like `value=the-encoded-json-string`.

Or as an alternative, if you want to send a string via `application/json`, See [my thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53698938/10091607) for more details.

> the current objective is to add or remove any MainGroup / SubGroup / NanoGroup/ FeatureName in the current Jsondata which I believe will need traversing through the data.
>
> With the current working scenario the only level to which I can access data is value.KanMainGroupList.

I believe either traversing or using LINQ will make it. But since we don't know the scenario, we can't provide any detailed suggestion.

There's no problem in your implementation. My best guess is that you want a fluent API to access sub list? If that's the case, use `[SelectMany()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8)` to flatten sub groups.