# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building .Net Core 3.1 Web API. To send requests to Web API. I'm using System.Net.Http library. I put JSON into POST request body. This is Web API side handler:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public int HandleRequest([FromBody] string jsonString)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The code below sends empty ArrayList to Web API but it always returns "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value line 1, position 1.".

```
var serializedData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new ArrayList());
var content = new StringContent(serializedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = client.PostAsync(url, content);
return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I've tried to use JsonConvert and played around the object to serialize but it always returns the same error. But then I've found that if I make serialization twice then it starts working. So code below works - sends the request without any errors and the data on Web API side is correct.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedData = serializer.Serialize(serializer.Serialize(new ArrayList()));
var content = new StringContent(serializedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = client.PostAsync(url, content);
return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Why do I need to do double serialization to make it work?

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` and `ArrayList` isn't recommended for use

Comment: ? only difference between these two snippets appears to be that you store the serializer in a local in the second one. You're not serializing twice here, as you suggest.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError he is serializing twice. First call serialize `ArrayList` to `string`, then `string` to `string` - that's why endpoint works.

Comment: `[FromBody] string jsonString` replace to `[FromBody] ArrayList arrayList` or any collection.

Comment: @Hostel: So he is - I see it now.

Comment: @YuryTsibin  both answers below are correct.  This is a duplicate of another SO question which provides a little more detail on the issue which is that because you're asking for "string" the web api expects a quoted string as the body.  That question/answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684038/400-bad-request-when-trying-to-post-simple-value-to-an-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you are using async methods you should add await keyword:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
return await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Secondly, you are sending an array, so why not just try to send it and get as object not string:

```
var updateData = new ArrayList();
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateData);
var content = new StringContent(jsonObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var res = await apiClient.PutAsync(url, content);
```

And then in WebAPI:

```
[HttpPost]
public int HandleRequest([FromBody] ArrayList list)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var serializedData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new ArrayList());
Console.WriteLine(serializedData);
// Output: []

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedData = serializer.Serialize(serializer.Serialize(new ArrayList()));
Console.WriteLine(serializedData);
// Output: "[]"
```

You have an error because your endpoint expects string but in first serialization you are sending an array.
Second serialization works, because first you serialize `ArrayList` to `string` and then that `string` to `string`. In the end you by accident send a serialized string and endpoint can deserialize it.

Error `"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value line 1, position 1."` means that server receives at first character `[` but it expects `"` because it tries deserialize JSON to string - but it was array.